# Get id where all rows are true (sqalchemy)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to find a simple way of finding a specific form or forms where all items with the `form_id` are active.

Here is my `Messages` table:

```
class Messages(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Messages'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    form_id = db.Column(db.String(12), index=True)
    message_text = db.Column(db.String(1000), nullable=True, unique=False, index=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean, unique=False, index=False, nullable=True, default=False)
```

The form in question has multiple fields and each field is an individual message. The whole form has a unique `form_id`.
I would like to query the database and get the `form_id` but only for those forms where **all** messages with the `form_id` have `active` set to `True`.

Something like:

```
alert_form_id = db.session.query(Messages.form_id).filter_by(active=True).first()
```

but this returns all form_id's even if a single message has `active=True`.

Is there a simple way to do this with sqalchemy or do i need to check the number of items vs. number of "active" items for every form_id?

Comment: Isn't the syntax `message = db.session.query(Messages).filter_by(active=True).first()` without the `.form_id`?. You get a message object, then call `message.form_id`. I can't test this now.

Comment: I think since you are using flask_sqlalchemy you should use the following. `alert_form_id = Messages.query.with_entities(Messages.form_id).filter_by(active=True).first()`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? For example PostgreSQL has `every` / `bool_and` aggregate. If not supported, you can use the fact that FORALL ( p ) -> NOT EXISTS ( NOT p ).

Comment: @IljaEverilä i'm currently using SQLite but i have been going back and forward on migrating to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @MaiconMauricio I'm not sure there is a difference. Yes i can get the message object and then do `message.form_id` but since i actually need only the `form_id` i can call it directly with `query(Messages.form_id)`.. either way produces the same result I'm not sure if there is any difference from the performance perspective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the exact requirement and the model/relationship definitions there are cleaner ways to implement it. But the below should work for the model you shared. The idea is to count that total number of Messages is the same as the number of active messages for each form (leaving no inactive messages):

```
q = (
    session.query(Message.form_id).group_by(Message.form_id)
    .having(func.sum(case([(Message.active == True, 1)], else_=0)) == func.count(Message.id))
)
```

---

*Alternative solution:* find those (**distinct**) `form_id` values, for which there are no *inactive* Messages:

```
M2 = aliased(Message)
q = session.query(Message.form_id.distinct()).filter(
    ~session.query(M2)
    .filter(Message.form_id == M2.form_id)
    .filter(M2.active == False)
    .exists()
)
```

Comment: Neat and portable! I just think they were after `active = TRUE` :)

Comment: Thank you, @IljaEverilä. Corrected the answer to reflect your comment, which is spot-on.

Comment: This is great! I'm using the first solution but i just noticed you added the alternative. Would you say the alternative solution would be faster since its not counting every entry?

Comment: I think the performance difference will depend on the size of your table, number of entries per form_id and indices. More a matter of a taste I would say