# Implement Python's `all()` function in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a boolean value from this, but I need to use the result in the form of an SQL expression:

```
states = [entry.state for entry in cls.entries.all()]
is_valid = all(state == "VALID" for state in states)
```

Is there any built in function in SQLAlchemy to map this `all()` function into an SQL expression getting the same logic?

Comment: Thanks for the answer @python_user! I need all rows to have the value. I guess I should compare it to the number of rows somehow.

Comment: You're trying to produce a hybrid property?

Comment: @IljaEverilä I am actually trying to create an expression for a hybrid property and implement certain python expressions/logic with sql ones.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the class definition. For example it looks like `cls.entries` is another hybrid prop, or a dynamic relationship, or such. If that is the case, then `cls.entries.all()` might be performing an unnecessary fetch — maybe. `all(p(x) for x in s)` in Python is equivalent with `not any(not p(x) for x in s)`, and the same applies in SQL; you can use `EXISTS` to produce the equivalent of `FORALL`.

Comment: `cls.entries` is indeed another hybrid prop. I've made an expression for that too so I can query on it but that one had only a simple return field value, no fancy python functions.

Comment: Assuming the related class is called `Entry`, you could use `~cls.entries.filter(Entry.state != "VALID").exists()` (might require some tuning of correlation) as `is_valid`. That reads "No entry exists that is not valid." Sound logic, terrible English.

Comment: Please take a look at this answer, both solutions of which should give you an idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67454516/99594.